# The Last of the Sons of Fëanor

Tags: knowledge

Essicilmë and anessi?  Or maybe something else…

1. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 67 32 2e 77 69 6b 69 61 2e 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b 69 65 2e 6e 65 74 2f 5f 5f 63 62 32 30 30 37 30 38 31 32 30 35 35 33 32 30 2f 68 61 72 72 79 70 6f 74 74 65 72 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 39 2f 39 38 2f 53 6e 61 70 65 5f 35 74 68 79 65 61 72 2e 6a 70 67 20
2. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 67 32 2e 77 69 6b 69 61 2e 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b 69 65 2e 6e 65 74 2f 5f 5f 63 62 32 30 30 38 30 33 31 38 32 31 35 37 34 34 2f 6c 6f 74 72 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 34 2f 34 33 2f 41 72 61 67 6f 72 6e 33 2e 6a 70 67
3. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 62 65 61 73 74 73 6f 66 77 61 72 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 77 70 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2f 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 73 2f 32 30 31 35 2f 30 31 2f 6f 57 6f 70 30 2e 6a 70 67 20
4. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 67 33 2e 77 69 6b 69 61 2e 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b 69 65 2e 6e 65 74 2f 5f 5f 63 62 32 30 31 32 30 36 30 34 31 35 30 36 31 35 2f 6c 6f 74 72 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 64 2f 64 32 2f 57 61 72 5f 6f 66 5f 77 72 61 74 68 2e 6a 70 67 20
5. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 74 6f 6c 6b 69 65 6e 67 61 74 65 77 61 79 2e 6e 65 74 2f 77 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 74 68 75 6d 62 2f 64 2f 64 65 2f 4b 69 6d 62 65 72 6c 79 5f 2d 5f 4e 69 65 6e 6f 72 5f 4e 69 6e 69 65 6c 2e 6a 70 67 2f 32 35 30 70 78 2d 4b 69 6d 62 65 72 6c 79 5f 2d 5f 4e 69 65 6e 6f 72 5f 4e 69 6e 69 65 6c 2e 6a 70 67
6. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 67 31 30 2e 64 65 76 69 61 6e 74 61 72 74 2e 6e 65 74 2f 64 64 36 63 2f 69 2f 32 30 31 33 2f 30 37 35 2f 66 2f 37 2f 6e 65 73 73 61 5f 62 79 5f 65 73 74 65 6c 69 6e 61 6b 69 6e 61 2d 64 35 79 38 69 7a 61 2e 6a 70 67
7. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 66 63 30 30 2e 64 65 76 69 61 6e 74 61 72 74 2e 6e 65 74 2f 66 73 37 30 2f 66 2f 32 30 31 31 2f 33 32 33 2f 65 2f 32 2f 6d 6f 72 77 65 6e 5f 62 79 5f 65 6b 75 6b 61 6e 6f 76 61 2d 64 34 67 6f 30 36 6e 2e 6a 70 67
8. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 32 2e 66 61 6e 70 6f 70 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 70 68 6f 74 6f 73 2f 39 35 30 30 30 30 30 2f 50 69 70 70 69 6e 2d 54 6f 6f 6b 2d 70 69 70 70 69 6e 2d 74 6f 6f 6b 2d 39 35 36 30 30 30 37 2d 34 35 30 2d 35 37 30 2e 6a 70 67 20
9. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 6f 72 69 67 30 30 2e 64 65 76 69 61 6e 74 61 72 74 2e 6e 65 74 2f 64 62 39 36 2f 66 2f 32 30 31 32 2f 30 38 30 2f 36 2f 61 2f 65 6c 75 5f 74 68 69 6e 67 6f 6c 5f 62 79 5f 65 6b 75 6b 61 6e 6f 76 61 2d 64 34 74 67 78 35 63 2e 6a 70 67
10. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 73 74 61 74 69 63 2e 74 75 6d 62 6c 72 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 65 37 63 32 34 35 35 64 39 62 62 61 31 62 37 62 35 33 33 35 38 64 61 35 36 66 38 31 63 38 65 66 2f 69 76 69 67 64 36 6b 2f 56 57 47 6d 68 37 37 6c 66 2f 74 75 6d 62 6c 72 5f 73 74 61 74 69 63 5f 74 75 6d 62 6c 72 5f 6d 34 61 71 78 31 6f 6b 77 6c 31 71 6d 78 61 61 38 6f 31 5f 35 30 30 2e 6a 70 67
11. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 76 69 67 6e 65 74 74 65 33 2e 77 69 6b 69 61 2e 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b 69 65 2e 6e 65 74 2f 6c 6f 74 72 66 61 6e 6f 6e 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 32 2f 32 30 2f 4e 69 6d 6c 6f 74 68 5f 45 6c 75 63 68 ee 6c 2e 70 6e 67 2f 72 65 76 69 73 69 6f 6e 2f 6c 61 74 65 73 74 3f 63 62 3d 32 30 31 33 31 32 33 30 30 32 31 30 35 32
12. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 76 65 72 73 61 70 68 69 6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 63 61 70 73 2f 74 74 74 2f 31 38 73 68 61 64 6f 77 66 61 78 2f 73 68 61 64 6f 77 66 61 78 33 39 2e 6a 70 67
13. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 67 33 2e 77 69 6b 69 61 2e 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b 69 65 2e 6e 65 74 2f 5f 5f 63 62 32 30 30 37 30 37 31 39 32 31 34 39 32 33 2f 6c 6f 74 72 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 64 2f 64 34 2f 43 69 72 64 61 6e 2e 6a 70 67
14. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 67 32 2e 77 69 6b 69 61 2e 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b 69 65 2e 6e 65 74 2f 5f 5f 63 62 32 30 31 31 31 31 31 36 30 37 32 31 34 35 2f 6c 6f 74 72 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 31 2f 31 38 2f 56 61 72 64 61 5f 62 79 5f 47 75 73 74 61 76 6f 4d 61 6c 65 6b 2e 6a 70 67 20
15. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 67 32 2e 77 69 6b 69 61 2e 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b 69 65 2e 6e 65 74 2f 5f 5f 63 62 32 30 30 37 30 39 31 39 31 39 32 34 33 32 2f 6c 6f 74 72 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 36 2f 36 61 2f 54 75 72 69 6e 2d 41 72 74 77 6f 72 6b 2e 4a 50 47
16. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 76 69 67 6e 65 74 74 65 33 2e 77 69 6b 69 61 2e 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b 69 65 2e 6e 65 74 2f 64 65 61 64 6c 69 65 73 74 66 69 63 74 69 6f 6e 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 37 2f 37 35 2f 35 39 37 70 78 2d 54 68 65 6f 64 65 6e 5f 72 69 64 65 72 2e 6a 70 67 2f 72 65 76 69 73 69 6f 6e 2f 6c 61 74 65 73 74 3f 63 62 3d 32 30 31 32 30 33 32 36 30 31 30 31 30 39
17. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 74 65 64 6e 61 73 6d 69 74 68 2e 70 6f 76 65 72 65 6c 6c 6f 6d 65 64 69 61 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 77 70 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2f 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 73 2f 32 30 31 32 2f 30 37 2f 54 4e 2d 42 65 72 65 6e 73 5f 4c 65 61 70 2e 6a 70 67
18. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 6f 72 69 67 31 32 2e 64 65 76 69 61 6e 74 61 72 74 2e 6e 65 74 2f 32 61 33 35 2f 66 2f 32 30 31 34 2f 32 34 30 2f 61 2f 34 2f 61 34 63 39 33 32 37 39 30 30 36 65 36 64 31 65 31 36 36 61 37 38 62 32 38 63 62 33 37 35 62 30 2d 64 33 30 69 7a 66 6d 2e 6a 70 67
19. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 77 65 61 72 79 73 6c 6f 74 68 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 47 61 6c 6c 65 72 79 2f 41 63 74 6f 72 73 4d 2f 32 31 38 32 32 2d 32 35 35 37 35 2e 67 69 66
20. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 6f 72 69 67 30 32 2e 64 65 76 69 61 6e 74 61 72 74 2e 6e 65 74 2f 62 37 39 31 2f 66 2f 32 30 31 33 2f 30 33 37 2f 35 2f 36 2f 74 68 6f 72 69 6e 5f 6f 61 6b 65 6e 73 68 69 65 6c 64 5f 6b 69 6e 67 5f 75 6e 64 65 72 5f 74 68 65 5f 6d 6f 75 6e 74 61 69 6e 5f 62 79 5f 64 72 6b 61 79 38 35 2d 64 35 75 30 6b 6c 73 2e 6a 70 67
21. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 67 33 2e 77 69 6b 69 61 2e 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b 69 65 2e 6e 65 74 2f 5f 5f 63 62 32 30 30 37 30 33 32 32 32 31 35 39 32 33 2f 6c 6f 74 72 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 34 2f 34 34 2f 47 69 6c 2d 67 61 6c 61 64 31 31 2e 6a 70 67
22. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 69 6d 67 31 2e 77 69 6b 69 61 2e 6e 6f 63 6f 6f 6b 69 65 2e 6e 65 74 2f 5f 5f 63 62 32 30 31 32 31 31 31 34 31 36 31 35 31 37 2f 6c 6f 74 72 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 37 2f 37 61 2f 4d 61 6e 77 65 5f 53 75 6c 69 6d 6f 5f 62 79 5f 47 75 73 74 61 76 6f 4d 61 6c 65 6b 2e 6a 70 67
23. 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 73 33 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 74 65 6c 65 76 69 63 65 6e 74 72 6f 2f 70 6f 72 74 61 64 61 73 2f 73 61 72 75 6d 61 6e 2e 6a 70 67 3f 6d 74 69 6d 65 3d 32 30 31 34 30 35 32 38 31 31 34 31 30 33

Seems long, but the output is much shorter.  Most know how to deal with the given text, but there is a second, "slightly" more labour intensive step.  Each part yields one letter.  A liking for Middle-earth may help.  Please edit tags.

Comment: @mmking maybe a little bit of research etc. is necessary.  Knowing the stories makes it go faster.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> Here are what the links are to make this puzzle accessible for those with more specialized talents:
> http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070812055320/harrypotter/images/9/98/Snape_5thyear.jpg
> http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20080318215744/lotr/images/4/43/Aragorn3.jpg
> http://www.beastsofwar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/oWop0.jpg
> http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120604150615/lotr/images/d/d2/War_of_wrath.jpg
> http://tolkiengateway.net/w/images/thumb/d/de/Kimberly_-_Nienor_Niniel.jpg/250px-Kimberly_-_Nienor_Niniel.jpg
> http://img10.deviantart.net/dd6c/i/2013/075/f/7/nessa_by_estelinakina-d5y8iza.jpg
> http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/323/e/2/morwen_by_ekukanova-d4go06n.jpg
> http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/9500000/Pippin-Took-pippin-took-9560007-450-570.jpg
> http://orig00.deviantart.net/db96/f/2012/080/6/a/elu_thingol_by_ekukanova-d4tgx5c.jpg
> http://static.tumblr.com/e7c2455d9bba1b7b53358da56f81c8ef/ivigd6k/VWGmh77lf/tumblr_static_tumblr_m4aqx1okwl1qmxaa8o1_500.jpg
> http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/lotrfanon/images/2/20/Nimloth_Eluchîl.png/revision/latest?cb=20131230021052
> http://versaphile.com/caps/ttt/18shadowfax/shadowfax39.jpg
> http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070719214923/lotr/images/d/d4/Cirdan.jpg
> http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111116072145/lotr/images/1/18/Varda_by_GustavoMalek.jpg
> http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070919192432/lotr/images/6/6a/Turin-Artwork.JPG
> http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/deadliestfiction/images/7/75/597px-Theoden_rider.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120326010109
> http://tednasmith.poverellomedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/TN-Berens_Leap.jpg
> http://orig12.deviantart.net/2a35/f/2014/240/a/4/a4c93279006e6d1e166a78b28cb375b0-d30izfm.jpg
> http://www.wearysloth.com/Gallery/ActorsM/21822-25575.gif
> http://orig02.deviantart.net/b791/f/2013/037/5/6/thorin_oakenshield_king_under_the_mountain_by_drkay85-d5u0kls.jpg
> http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070322215923/lotr/images/4/44/Gil-galad11.jpg
> http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121114161517/lotr/images/7/7a/Manwe_Sulimo_by_GustavoMalek.jpg
> http://s3.amazonaws.com/televicentro/portadas/saruman.jpg?mtime=20140528114103

Comment: He obviously loves books like LOtR and HP… maybe figuring out what each link depicts? Essicilmë and anessi are like names, right?